# Form associating every attribute with object except for image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload images and associate them with objects with rails, and I am having trouble figuring out why every attribute is becoming associated with the correct object from the form except for the image. Here are the relevant files:

views/cars/_form

```
<%= form_for @car do |f| %>

<% if @car.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @car.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <%= f.label :make %>
  <%= f.text_field :make %><br>

  <%= f.label :model %>
  <%= f.text_field :model %><br>

  <%= f.label :color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color %><br>

  <%= f.label :year %>
  <%= f.text_field :year %><br>

  <%= f.label :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<%end%>
```

car.rb

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :image_file_name

  belongs_to :user
 has_many :categories, through: :awards
  validates :year, length: {is: 4}
  has_attached_file :image,
                  styles: {
                      thumb: ["300x300#", :jpeg],
                      original: [:jpeg]
                  },
                  convert_options: {
                      thumb: "-quality 70 -strip",
                      original: "-quality 90"
                  }

  validates_attachment :image,
                     content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/ },
                     size: { less_than: 4.megabyte }

  scope :classic, ->(time) { where("cars.year < ?", time)}

end
```

I have looked all over and have yet to find any instances of this problem. The make, model, color, and year are all being associated with new car objects, but the images are missing. Does anyone know why this may be the case? Thank you in advance!

Edit: This is the last object I created, it looks like it is associating everything but a filename to the image. Hmm...

```
2.3.3 :001 > Car.last
  Car Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" ORDER BY "cars"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Car id: 5, make: "Honda", model: "Civic", year: 2002, color: "Black", user_id: 1, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 49575, image_updated_at: "2018-03-02 01:04:21", created_at: "2018-03-02 00:29:26", updated_at: "2018-03-02 01:04:21", image: nil>
```

Comment: your image is uploaded.  why did you add a separate field for image only?

Answer (score 0):

The `attr_accessor :image_file_name` in car.rb was not allowing the filename to be associated with the created object. Once I deleted that, images saved and were associated with objects upon submission of the form.